# Adding a custom attribute to a form in yii2

Tags: jquery, html, forms, yii2

Am creating an active form and i would like to add a custom attribute.
This is a normal form field

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->textInput() ?>
```

I would like it to be in the form of

```
<label class="input"> 
 <i class="icon-append fa fa-envelope"></i>
    <input type="password" name="email" placeholder="Password>
    <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Needed to verify your account</b>
 </label>
```

The above is a normal html form field that i would like the yii2 active form to be like

I have tried

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->
   textInput(["placeholder"=>"password"])->label(["class"=>"input"])?>
```

Am stuck on how ill add the tooltip and the icon

The final form field should be like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Options](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#field()-detail) :

For example,

```
$fieldOptions = [
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-group has-feedback'],
    'inputTemplate' => "{input}<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback'></span>",
];

<?= $form->field($model, 'password', $fieldOptions)->label(false)->passwordInput(['placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('password')]) ?>
```